# Centos - Automatically issue a command after rebooting

Tags: centos, boot, linux

I need to automatically issue a command on my CentOS 4.8 server after it reboots and/or powers up. Can someone please tell me where I can place this? Is there a configuration file somewhere for this?

Thanks,

-M

Comment: How soon after reboot does this command need to be executed? Before other daemons start? rc.local is about last in line.

Comment: Preferably about the last in line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just put in your crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/whatever
```

This has the advantage that it can be done by non-superusers, which rc.local needs.

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can run scripts upon boot by placing them in the /etc/rc.local file.